# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called on tableView reloadData

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView on one view that loads in data at the start of the application, and then later when a user enters text into a box and hits a button, I re-query the database, re-populate the original NSMutableArray that stores the data for the table.

All of that is working perfectly. In some logging statements I can tell that the array has the correct information, the numberOfRowsInSection method is returning the proper count, and is being called after the reload is called.

However, the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called the second time (after the reload) and the table data is never updated.

I've spent hours searching the net and I've found nothing that helps. Can anyone help?

All code is at:
http://github.com/botskonet/inmyspot

The specific reload is being called at:
http://github.com/botskonet/inmyspot/blob/master/Classes/InMySpotViewController.m

Roughly Line 94

From:
http://github.com/botskonet/inmyspot/blob/master/Classes/PlateFormViewController.m

Roughly line 101

A bit more info: once the new data has been added to the mutablearray, if I try to start scrolling the table, it eventually dies with:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (29) beyond bounds (29)'"

Which I assume means the table cells can't find any data in the array to match the scroll position, which seems to be because the array has the new data, but the table doesn't.

Comment: Where are you getting a ".count" property on NSMutableArray? Unless I'm missing something it should be `[plates count]`, not `plates.count`.

Comment: Not entirely sure, it's sample code I borrowed from a demo. It is working fine though. I've logged it out and it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing the same issue.  My problem was similar: I have a UIViewController subclass `(MyViewController)` that contains a few things, including a reference to my subclass of `UITableViewController (MyTableViewController)`.  In `MyViewController.xib`, in order to make sure that the tableView that is loaded by the `MyViewController` is the same one as the one loaded in `MyTableViewController`, in Interface Builder I hooked up the reference from the tableView in `MyViewController` and made it point to `MyTableViewController's` view property.

Here's a picture, since actions in Interface Builder are so hard to describe: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your reload is not being called because you haven't setup your delegates for UITableView properly.

```
@interface InMySpotViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
}
```

Also you overwrite mainDelegate.plates here:

```
NSMutableArray *platesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                mainDelegate.plates = platesArray;
                [platesArray release];
```

Why not combine your two controllers. The way your doing it is leading to most of your problems. You create a new InMySpotViewController unnecessarily in PlateFormViewController.

Comment: I've updated the delegates for the controller, so far it had no effect. However, the code that updates the plates array is actually supposed to - it's loading in a new set of database results. Thanks!

Comment: I've combined the two controllers, and I'm again getting the table covering up all of the other text/button elements. http://github.com/botskonet/inmyspot/tree/views

Comment: Are you setting the frame size of the UIViewControllers appropriately?

Comment: You haven't added the UITextField, UILabel, or UIButton to the viewController (InMySpotViewController), using addSubViews, that's why they don't show up.

Comment: @Jordan   Even if you don't declare your class as complying with the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols, as long as you implement all the delegate/data source calls you need, they will get called.  The protocol adherence declaration is mostly a compiler convenience.  I've not run into a case where the UIKit stuff actually tests compliance to the protocol, they seem to just test that the routines/selectors are there.  (And of course, you have set the delegate and datasource to point to your object that implements them)

Answer (score 1):

In `plateLookup` you clobber the existing array:

```
    NSMutableArray *platesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    mainDelegate.plates = platesArray;
    [platesArray release];
```

After this you reload the table.  The array has zero elements so `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is never called.

Edit:
You also create a new view controller

```
        InMySpotViewController *viewController = [[InMySpotViewController alloc] init]; 
        [viewController refreshTable];
```

So you're not even reloading the table that's visible on the screen.

Comment: The plates array "clobber" is supposed to be loading in a new set of database results, so I believe this is how I want it to work. The plates array is properly receiving the new data set. However, I suppose I am creating a new view which makes sense why the tableView I have on screen isn't updating. How can I fix that?

These views are separate because I had previous problem where the table was covering up my other elements no matter how I tried to do it, and no one had any ideas why.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the end of plateLookup, then inspect the contents of platesArray.  You'll see that the array isn't reloading like you think it is.  That's why you're getting the Index out of Bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some debugging by a family member I've determined the following issues were the cause:

The `inMySpotViewController` was setup as a `UITableViewController` not a `UIViewController` which is why the table was covering up everything else. I changed it to a `UIViewController` and then added a new `UITableView`:

```
IBOutlet UITableView *myTblView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTblView;
```

And then referenced that table view throughout my code. This code was done on the single-view branch so it's now working properly.

The platesArray kept being mentioned as a problem, but it's not because the out of bounds was happening because the array was successfully being updated, whereas the table view was not (so I was trying to scroll to an index in the array that didn't exist, but I knew that was the problem since they table didn't visually update).

I had successfully logged out the contents of the revised plates array after re-writing it's values and they were all correct, and plates.count was returning the proper values, so it was not getting "clobbered" in anyway.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I traced it to having a tableView property in the interface.  I don't think I added this myself but who cares, it was masking the UITableViewController's own tableView property.  I removed it, the project continued to build, but now when I return from the pushed viewcontroller back to the first UITableViewController, the proper sequence happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Most of the answers from google talked about **`delegate`**. But I was sure that my **`delegate`** and **`data source`** were set properly.

Latter, I found that the problem is the return value of this method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In my code, I rewrote the method like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _dataArray.count;
}
```

But when checking this break point, I found `_dataArray` is nil somehow. This method should return a positive integer, otherwise

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

might not be called.

I hope it can be helpful.