# UITableView delegates are not called

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a tableview with external delegate controller. Despite content table view array is well populated, and 
`numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and
`-tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` are called, 
 but`-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called.

Issued table view is set in that ways:

```
CompeticionViewController.h

....

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *calendarioTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  calendarioViewController *calendarioController;

....

calendarioTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];

            calendarioController  = [[calendarioViewController alloc] init];

            [calendarioTable setDelegate:calendarioController];

            [calendarioTable setDataSource:calendarioController];

            calendarioController.calendarioArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [calendarioController.calendarioArray addObjectsFromArray: self.calendarioarray];

            [calendarioTable reloadData];
```

EDITED:

```
calendarioViewController.m

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [calendarioArray count];

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: can you please post your numberOfSectionsInTableView  and numberOfRowsInSection section code..

Comment: what the `[calendarioArray count]` ?

Comment: You are saying numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are getting called, but not cellForRowAtIndexPath.. AFAIK the only chance of happening it is when your [calendarioArray count] is zero.. Are you sure you populated the array..

Comment: What do you see if you put `NSLog(@"%@", calendarioArray);` before returning the count?

Comment: Yes, it's populated, NSLog dumps all content correctly. It's very strange. Thanks

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429670/cellforrowatindexpath-not-being-called-on-tableview-reloaddata

Answer (score 4):

In .xib file link delegate and datasource with File's owner or write

```
tableview.delegate=self

tableview.datasource=self;
```

Comment: It has externals controller, and it is  delegated to it: [calendarioTable setDelegate:calendarioController];
[calendarioTable setDataSource:calendarioController]; Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have used `IBOulet` for `tableview` then why are u `allocating` it as its `not need memory already allocated`.

Now check in `xib` of your view controller that `tableview` is `binded` and its `delegate` and `datasource` provided to `file owner`.

-----------------------------------------**OR**------------------------------------------------

`add` this line in `viewDidLoad method`

```
yourtableview.delegate=self

yourtableview.datasource=self;
```

Now After using `IBOulet` for `tableview` you will have bind it with file owner and ViewController `interface implements` both the `<UITableViewDelegate>` and `<UITableViewDataSource>` `protocols`

Now `check array` you are `providing` to `tableview` has `content` in it

**Edit** : Add OR code and done formatting

Comment: If I delete allocated line, execution process doesn't enter in numberOfSectionsInTableView: and -tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:. maybe the problem is memory management with properties?

Comment: After using IBOulet for tableview you will have bind it with file owner and ViewController interface implements both the <UITableViewDelegate> and <UITableViewDataSource> protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your CompeticionViewController interface implements both the `<UITableViewDelegate>` and `<UITableViewDataSource>` protocols.